# How to remove index.html from url

Tags: html, .htaccess, redirect

I have uploaded my HTML files to my website. Now i need to find a way to redirect users to a Home.html page when they enters www.mywebsite.com 
i have tried to to this in htaccess but it did not work, i am not sure if it is correct

```
RewriteEngine On
#if request is mywebsite.co.uk/something OR
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mywebsite\.co.uk$ [OR]

# or www. mywebsite.co.uk/something
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mywebsite\.co.uk$

# but not mywebsite.co.uk/Home.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/Home.html/

#change it to mywebsite.co.uk/Home.html/something
RewriteRule (.*) /Home.html/$1 [R=301]
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove your code and put this only @ `.haccess`  file :

```
DirectoryIndex Home.html
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the .htaccess file is in the directory where you want to change the index.html file